# Как получить рассчитываемые поля, которых нет в БД?

Tags: sql

Мне нужно составить запрос и получить 4 колонки со следующими атрибутами: наименование актива, общее количество активов, зарезервированное число активов, свободное число активов. В моей БД есть только атрибут "Наименование актива", остальных 3 атрибутов нет в БД и они рассчитываются на лету. То есть в конце должна получиться следующая сводная таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу ли я получить данную таблицу при помощи SQL? Пока мне удалось выгрузить только два первых столбца, SQL следующий:

```
SELECT ref_model_id, COUNT(ref_model_id) FROM am_asset 
WHERE status = 'на_складе'
GROUP BY ref_model_id;
```

Здесь нужно использовать JOIN или вложенные запросы?

Comment: Условная агрегация. `SELECT .. , SUM(CASE WHEN busy THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS busy_amount, ..`

Comment: Добрый день! Не могу понять, как в моем случае поможет условная агрегация. Мне кажется тут все-таки нужно использовать JOIN. Пока получилось вот так:
`SELECT ref_model_id, COUNT(*) AS total_assets, COUNT(*) AS reserved_assets
FROM am_asset
LEFT JOIN am_asset_reservation ON am_asset_reservation.ref_asset_id = am_asset.id 
WHERE status = 'на_складе'
GROUP BY ref_model_id`
Но итоговый результат меня не устраивает: по итогу у меня общее кол-во активов равно зарезервированному количеству, что не всегда так. Как мне поставить условие так, чтобы зарезервированные активы правильно считались?

Comment: За зарезервированность актива у меня отвечает атрибут "is_active" из другой таблицы. Поэтому мне кажется в моем случае JOIN'ы неизбежны.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169) особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: Спасибо! Ознакомлюсь)